# python not operator with parenthesis

Tags: python, logic, brackets, not-operator

I have a simple logic if statement returning an invalid syntax error. The statement is:

```
if (a[1] != None and a[2] != None and !(a[3] == None and a[4] == None)):
```

The invalid syntax is the third ! operator. Any reason why this would not work? Is there another operator I am supposed to use in this situation?

So the logic is essentially: `a[1] ^ a[2] ^ (a[3] v a[4])` (where these denote having values). Hence the reverse logic for getting no `None` values is:

```
!a[1] ^ !a[2] ^ !(a[3] ^ a[4])
```

I'm pretty sure my logic maths is right, so how do I get the result I require?

*Background info: Python 2.7.10, overall code is pulling data out of an SQL Server 2008 table, manipulating it and then inserting it into a different table that doesn't allow NULL values, and the original table is littered with NULLs

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logical not operator in python is not `!` but rather is `not`.

You want:

```
if (a[1] != None and a[2] != None and not (a[3] == None and a[4] == None)):
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick. Thank you for the quick response. Have to wait 10 mins to accept the value....

Comment: @shawn-mehan is right, by the way.  My suggestion was just the minimal change to make it run.

Answer (score 2):

Well, stylistically, when using `None` it is preferred to use `is` and `is not` rather than `==` and `!=`, so

```
if (a[1] is not None and a[2] is not None) and not (a[3] is None and a[4] is None):
```